# How to set UITabBar touch area

Tags: touch, uitabbar, overlap

I have come across the `UITabBar` touching area problem. Extra touching area (about 5 pixels) above the `UITabBar` is counted to be the `UITabBar`.  All objects being put in that area will be blocked and `UITabBar` will react instead.

I found some people asked about the same question (the following links) and could not get answer.

Could someone please help?

[Touch above the uiTabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205554/touch-above-the-uitabbar)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270517/uitabbar-line-above-the-bar-touch-problem

[UITabBar / UIToolBar overlap problem (iphone sdk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611578/uitabbar-uitoolbar-overlap-problem-iphone-sdk?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @NAZIK  Haven't got any solution...