# How to reduce the click access length of a tab in uitabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

The title won't clear the actual problem. Let me explain clearly.

I have a tabbarcontoller in the viewcontroller which is the main view controller of the single view application project.

I added Navigationcontrollers to the tabbarcontroller. So that I can navigate(push/pop) from one viewcontroller to other.

I added a subview to the mainview of a single navigation controller.

When I click the button near to the tabbar, it doesn't get clicked and the tabbaritem button gets access and shows that tab.

The below image will explain well,

[image]

If I click the show button, it opens the receipts tab.

How to reduce the click access boundary of the tabbar in tabbarcontroller?

I can't get any solution regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, i've written a bunch of applications which have controls near the tab bar and i've never encountered such behaviour.

Check if you have custom tabbar controller with custom frame.

Also try to use Reveal App (http://revealapp.com/) to check the buttons' frame at runtime, it will help you to understand what's going on. They have trial version as i remember.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: I'm not using custom tabbar controller

Comment: You are describing a none-native behaviour, so i think we need to gather more information :). Try RevealApp or test actual tabbar/button frames somehow else.

Comment: non-native behaviour? pl see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237456/how-to-set-uitabbar-touch-area).

Answer (score 0):

Choose the custom button for this and add in tabbar.